# Unity C# Serialize/Deserialize from json

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

**sry for eng**

Im new to c# and Unity, just trying to learn on something fun.

Im trying to build `Items stats` system where i can put everything about items in `json` file, load it on `void Start` and use this data. Also it could be used for different languages.

So i created `Item` class for items.

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public int itemId;
    public string itemName;
    public string itemDescription;
    public string itemType;
}
```

I decided to divide `Items` into several classes

I created `Food` class.

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class Food
{
    public Item Apple;
    public Item Plum;
}
```

So in `Food` class i can easily add more Items.

Here my `Json` file

```
{
  "Apple": {
    "itemId": 0,
    "itemName": "Apple",
    "itemDescription": "Juicy",
    "itemType": "Food"
  },
  "Plum": {
    "itemId": 1,
    "itemName": "Plum",
    "itemDescription": "Tasty",
    "itemType": "Food"
  }
}
```

So i created c# script which i gonna put on all my food prefabs, on game start it will parse data from `json` with selected language and save this data on each food prefab.

So im trying to do it like this :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class FoodStat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int itemId;
    public string itemName;
    public string itemDescription;
    public string itemType;

    void Awake()
    {
        FoodSetValues();
    }

    void FoodSetValues()
    {
        Food food = InitializeFoodLanguage();

        Item currItem = (Item)typeof(Food).GetProperty(gameObject.name).GetValue(food);
        itemId = currItem.itemId;
        itemName = currItem.itemName;
        itemDescription = currItem.itemDescription;
        itemType = currItem.itemType;
    }

    public Food InitializeFoodLanguage()
    {
        string pathFood = (Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Languages/en_Food.json");
        Food food = JsonUtility.FromJson<Food>(File.ReadAllText(pathFood));
        return food;
    }
}
```

So im trying to take prefab name (`gameObject.name`), which should be same as Object in `Food` class and then use parsed from `json` data. So each prefab will get data by Name.

It doesn't work, and seems like there is a better architecture, but i don't see it.

Always getting this error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
FoodStat.FoodSetValues () (at Assets/SCR_Items/FoodStat.cs:20)
FoodStat.Awake () (at Assets/SCR_Items/FoodStat.cs:13)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: which is the line 23 where the exception is generated? `currItem` can be null and thus accessing `currItem.itemId` can lead to the `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Oh sorry it was not last error, i changed it. 20 line is `Item currItem = (Item)typeof(Food).GetProperty(gameObject.name).GetValue(food);`
________
`gameObject.name` = `Apple`, but it doesn't work anyway :( Even if i write there `"Apple"`

Comment: I see a `GetProperty`, but your class only contains fields. Best practice would probably to make them properties (`get;set;`), but you can try `GetField` instead.
(Although deserialzing to a dictionary would feel better :) )

Comment: Omg `GetField` actually works! Wasted almost 2 days on this, thank you so much! Also tried to create dicionary, but can't even deserialize it T_T . Im just happy that works. Thank you again! <3